# Вынос метода шаблонного класса за класс

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

template <
    typename T,
    template < typename Y> class Allocator = std::allocator
>
class mVector
{
public:
    mVector();
};
```

visual studio предлагает создать реализацию конструктора за пределами класса в этом же файле:

```
template<typename T, class Allocator<typename Y>>
inline mVector<T, Allocator<Y>>::mVector()
{
}
```

И сама же потом отказывается запускать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если реализацию делать внутри класса, то всё ок

Comment: я помню у меня тоже с этим проблема была, жаль не помню как решал(

Comment: 1) не зачем его выносить 2) если выносить то параметры должны совпадать с объявленными в основном шаблоне

Comment: @user7860670 _должны совпадать с объявленными в основном шаблоне_ не могу понять как именно. Если так `template<typename T, template < typename Y> class Allocator>`, то получается https://ibb.co/kSx0VBz

Comment: `mVector<T, Allocator>::mVector`

Comment: @user7860670 так? https://ibb.co/BCdrK4p всё равно не получается(

Comment: а скобки где потерялись?

Comment: @user7860670 забыл скобки, с ними работает, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите реализовать вектор? Если да, то не совсем понятно для чего вам шаблонный аргумент Y, который передаётся в шаблон аллокатора, и, думаю, такой код более уместен:

---

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class mVector {
public:
  mVector();
};
template<class T, class Allocator>
mVector<T, Allocator>::mVector() {
}
```

---

Так и не допёр зачем вам такие шаблонные параметры, но если с ними, то так будет компилироваться и работать:

---

```
template<class T, template <class Y> class Allocator = std::allocator>
class mVector {
public:
  mVector();
};
template<class T, template <class Y> class Allocator>
mVector<T, Allocator>::mVector() {
}
```